# wrong count when using limit in mysql

Tags: mysql

Trying to figure out why this is returning the wrong count... it appears as if the limit has no effect on the count.

For example... if there are 20 computers found, but I am limiting it to 10 (licenses = 10) my return shows 20.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT count(computer_id)
    FROM computers
    WHERE account_id = :account_id
    ORDER BY computer_id ASC LIMIT 0, :licenses
");

$binding = array(
    'account_id' => $_SESSION['user']['account_id'],
    'licenses' => $_SESSION['user']['licenses']
);
$stmt->execute($binding);

$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

**this on the other hand would correctly return 10 :**

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT computer_id
    FROM computers
    WHERE account_id = :account_id
    ORDER BY computer_id ASC LIMIT 0, :licenses
");

$binding = array(
    'account_id' => $_SESSION['user']['account_id'],
    'licenses' => $_SESSION['user']['licenses']
);
$stmt->execute($binding);

$results = count($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0));
```

Comment: The `LIMIT` clause doesn't affect `COUNT` in your first query, `COUNT` will count all the rows and `LIMIT` is used to limit number of rows returned by the query after `COUNT` is done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is that your query's result has only one row, which is the total number of computers. Adding `limit 10` will have no effect, as you don't have more than 10 rows, but only one.

In your second query however, you have one row per computer. In that case, `limit 10` will limit your number of rows to 10.

---

What you can do however is something like this:

```
SELECT LEAST(10, count(computer_id))
FROM computers
WHERE account_id = :account_id
```

The result will be less than 10 if there are less than 10 computers with this licence, or will be 10 if there are at least 10 computers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a wrapping query, like that:

```
 SELECT count(computer_id)
    FROM (SELECT computer_id
      FROM computers
      WHERE account_id = :account_id
      ORDER BY computer_id ASC 
      LIMIT 0, :licenses) q;
```

The reason is that LIMIT clause only limit the number of returned rows, not the amount of rows on which the query runs. Hence if you want to count the returned rows, you have to consider the returned query as a source.

Comment: Useless and do not answer the question.